# Windows Hub Template App Accessing Textboxes

Tags: c#, windows, xaml

I am working on a Windows Store Hub App using XAML and C#.  I am not proficient in C#.  I understand the basics.  Please go easy on me.  I know you're wondering why I would even attempt this and so am I at this point.  I come from a web design background and could have used Javascript.  But I have really learned a lot by doing it and googling what I didn't understand.  The app controls really made me jump through hoops to do anything I wanted to do which must not be anything anyone else wants to do or there would be more documentation.  I should also mention I've never worked very much with forms so I don't have that background either.

I actually do have a question.  I am almost finished and on the last hub section.  I want to have textboxes that accept user input.  This will be for integers and will have a running total.  I can write that code albeit primitively.  What I can't do is access the textboxes inside the hub.  If I try to put them outside the hub I can but then they don't scroll with the page so I have textboxes floating there.

If they weren't in the hub I could just write:

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
           int a = Convert.ToInt32(tbOne.Text);
           int b = Convert.ToInt32(tbTwo.Text);
           int c = a + b;
           Total.Text = c.ToString();
      }
```

Of course, it will be more complicated than that but that is the basic idea.  Inside the hub, it does not recognize the x:name.

I would appreciate any insight into this or links if anyone has any.  I couldn't find anything by searching.

Answer (score 0):

Investigate the MVVM pattern. Accessing all controls by name is not the best way to do this. You want to set the data context of the your Hub to a seperate class that has properties like TextBox1Text and TextBox2Text and that implements INotifyPropertyChanged. Then in XAML bind those to the controls like . This will give you access to those controls nested in the Hub.